# Whether this feature exists in Azure or not, like while vmss instance is updating, no user can login into it through RDP?

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-virtual-network, azureportal, azure-vm-scale-set

In Azure, If our vmss instance is in update mode then how to stop user login into it through RDP or else how to stop connections of RDP to vmss instance?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there are two ways to update VMSS.

1. Install new software on a platform image at deployment time by using VM extensions.

In this way, When you use the powershell `Update-AzureRmVmss`, the VMSS will result in downtime and you cannot RDP to it.

2. Create a custom VM image that includes both the OS and the application in a single VHD

Actually, When you update your VMSS by reimaging those instances, you cannot RDP to or access those instances.

So, there isn't a feature to achieve your goal directly. But you can just feel free to update your VMSS and when the VMSS is updating, No one can RDP it.